# Mobile Optimization and Removing Active Content for eBay Listing Description

Tags: html, css, mobile, ebay-design-templates

I'm trying to rewrite our eBay listing body, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to stay current on web programming since I had my angelfire website over a decade ago.
I am very confused with this new CSS programming language, and how it works with HTML.
Here is the code that I came up with so far, but I am having some issues with it.
First of all, I want the links to be pop-ups, but ebay says it will be blocking all "active content", which I believe pop ups are included in.
The second issue is that listing description doesn't appear properly on a mobile device, automatically scaling the "Lorain Furniture" image on the top of listing. I'm not sure if it is an issue with the table, or the image. I feel like ive tried everything I've read on the internet, but I don't understand how to implement it.
Here is a link to the new eBay guidelines.
http://pages.ebay.com/sell/itemdescription/bestpractices.html
and a link to a listing with the new description.
http://www.ebay.com/itm/VTG-NEW-Amana-Gas-Range-Burner-Ignition-Switch-WPY0300521-AP6024095-/192070169613?ssPageName=STRK:MESE:IT

The code is as follows:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div style="display:none; color:white; font-size:1px;" id="HtmlAreaEditor">     [zipedit]</div>

<table id="BodyBackground" class="template0" width="100%" cellspacing="50" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffd635" align="center">

<tbody><tr><td>

<table id="PageContent" width="100%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="30" border="0" bgcolor="#00000" align="center">

<tbody><tr><td id="par0" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">

<center><img class="resize"  src="http://www.lorainfurniture.com/lorainfurniture.jpg"  alt="Lorain Furniture and Appliance">
</center>

<h2><font color="black" face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Details</font>  </h2>

<font size="3" color="black" face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif">All of our used parts have been tested while installed in the original appliance by one of our skilled and knowledgeable technicians.<br><br></font><font size="3" color="black" face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif"><font size="3" color="black" face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Typically, our items are photographed on a 1x1 inch grid. <br>You can determine the item's rough dimensions by counting the squares on the grid.<br><br></font></font><font size="3" color="black" face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif">We DO NOT sell parts for trial and error and would much rather see to it that you receive the proper part that you need to repair your appliance the first time around.<br>If you are unsure if this is the proper part for your appliance, visit <a href="http://lorain.appliancepartsupply.com/index.php">the Lorain Furniture and Appliance Online Parts Store</a> to enter your model number and view the diagrams and part numbers for your appliance. For Kenmore appliances, visit <a href="http://www.searspartsdirect.com">Sears Parts Direct</a>. <br><br>Should you not be able to sort it out on your own, or if you aren't sure what exactly is wrong with your appliance, feel free to send us a message through eBay.<br>Be sure to include your Model Number and Serial Number, along with a description of what is wrong with your appliance.<br>We will try to help you diagnose the issue and get your appliance back up and running in a timely manner.</font><font size="3" color="black" face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif"><br></font><br><font size="3" color="black" face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif">



<h2><font color="black" face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Returns</font></h2><p>You may return any part for 30 days, however, you will be subjected to a 20% restocking fee.<br>The restocking fee helps cover the cost of the time and effort involved in reprocessing the item, and the original cost of shipping and supplies.<br></p><p>Please note that any electrical parts cannot be returned once they've been installed on the appliance.<br>This is a standard policy among appliance parts dealers.</p><p>If you wish to make a return, please use the return system provided under your purchase history on the eBay website.</p><p>Please contact us if your part arrived damaged or is non-functioning before attempting a return. We will figure something out.<br></p></font>

<h2><font color="black" face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif">About Us<br></font></h2>

<font size="3" color="black" face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif">We have been in the used appliance business for over 15 years, and are a proud member of the Better Business Bureau. <br>Please feel free to contact us with any questions.<br><a href="http://www.lorainfurniture.com">www.LORAINFURNITURE.com</a><br><br>  </font></td></tr></tbody></table>

</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Thank you for any assistance that you can give.